# Java & MySQL Performance Issue

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have a bit of a performance problem. I have made a java program that constructs a database. The problem is when loading in the data. I am loading in 5,000 files into a sql Database. When the program starts off, it can process about 10% of the files in 10 minutes however it gets much slower as it progresses. Currently at 28% it is going to finish in 16 hours at its current rate. However that rate is slowing down considerably.

My question is why does the program get progressively slower as it runs and how to fix that.

EDIT: I have two versions. One is threaded (capped at 5 threads) and one is not. The difference between the two is negligible. I can post the code again if any one likes, but I took it out because I am now fairly certain that the bottle neck is the MySQL (Also appropriately re tagged). I went ahead and used batch inserts. This did cause an initial increase in speed but once again after processing about 30% of the data it does drop of quickly.

So SQL Points

1. My Engine for all 64 tables is InnoDB version 10.
2. The table have about 300k rows at this point (~30% of the data)
3. All tables have one "joint" primary key. A id and a date.
4. Looking at MySQL WorkBench I see that there is a query per thread (5 queries)
5. I am not sure the unit of time (Just reading from MySQL Administrator), but the queries to check if a file is already inserted are taking `300. (This query should be fast as it is a SELECT MyIndex from MyTable Limit 1 to 1 where Date = date.) As I have been starting and stopping the program I built in this check to see if the file was already inserted. That way I am able to start it after each change and see what if any improvement there is without starting the process again.
6. I am fairly certain that the degradation of preformance is related to the tables' sizes. (I can stop and start the program now and the process remains slow. It is only when the tables are small that the process is going at an acceptable speed.)
7. Please, please ask and I will post what ever information you need.

DONE! Well I just let it run for the 4 Days it needed to. Thank you all for the help.

Cheers,

--Orlan

Comment: how many records you have in one file?

Comment: There are 20 years of quarterly data; so 80 periods. 64 tables in each. 10000-8000 Rows per table per period (aka per file). So a table should be 10,000*80=800,000 rows. There are 10-150 fields per table. All fields are INT or BIGINT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Q1: Why does the program get progressively slower?**

In your problem space, you have 2 systems interacting: a **producer** that reads from the file system and *produces* data, and a **consumer** that transforms that data into records and stores them in the db. Your code is currently hard linking these two processes and your system works at the slowest speed of the two.

In your program you have a fixed arrival rate (1/sec - the wait when you've more than 10 threads running).  If you have indexes in the tables being filled, as the table grows bigger, inserts will take longer. That means that while your arrival rate is fixed at 1/sec, your exit rate is continuosly increasing. Therefore, you will be creating more and more threads that share the same CPU/IO resources and getting less things done per unit of time. Creating threads is also a very expensive operation.

**Q2:  Could it have to do with how I am constructing the queries from Strings?**

Only partially. Your string manipulation is a fixed cost in the system. It increases the cost it takes to service one request. But string operations are CPU bounded and your problem is I/O bounded, meaning that improving the string handling (that you should) will only marginally improve the performance of the system. ([See Amdahl's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law)).

**Q3: how to fix that (performance issue)**

- **Separate the file reader process from the db insert process**. See the [Consumer-Producer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer-consumer_problem) pattern. See also [Completion Service](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletionService.html) for an implementation built-in the JDK:

(FileReaderProducer) --> queue --> (DBBulkInsertConsumer)

- Don't create new Threads. Use the facilities provided by the java.util.concurrent package, like the executor service or the Completion service mentioned above. For a "bare" threadpool, use the [Executors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool%28int,%20java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory%29) factory.
- For this specific proble, having 2 separate thread pools, (one for the consumer, one for the producer) will allow you to tune your system for best performance. File reading improves with parallelization (up to your I/O bound), but db inserts are not (I/O + indexes + relational consistency checks), so you might need to limit the amount of file reading threads (3-5) to match the insertion rate (2-3). You can monitor the queue size to evaluate your system performance.
- Use JDBC bulk inserts: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/batch-insert-in-java-jdbc/
- Use StringBuilder instead of String concatenation. Strings in Java are immutable. That means that every time you do: `myString += ","`; you are creating a new String and making the old String elegible for garbage collection. In turn, this increases garbage collection performance penalties.

Comment: I am using the LOAD INFILE query now instead of constructing that massive string. I start fixing the threading.

Answer (score 1):

You can use direct insert from file to database (read [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-data.html)). It works faster. When I do same for postgres I get 20 times performance increase.

And also dounload Your kit profiler and profile your application for performance. Than you will see what takes your time.

Comment: I may suggest also to disable the indexes before the insertion (`alter table tbl disable keys`), and enable at the end (`alter table tbl enable keys`). If you don't need to read from the table while it's inserting, this might increase the speed.

Comment: alexey28: The problem is that the csv files I'm reading contain too much information. The first 30 or so cells are not needed.  And I have to add a cell every time.

Comment: in LOAD DATA INFILE you can specify columns set, ignoring, lines from what to start/stop read etc. It is preaty flexible. In other way if it will not sutisfy your requerements it will be faster read from initial file, save to format for direct loading to mysql and than loading. File operation much more faster comparing to db insert.

Comment: Thank you. I went ahead and did this. It is starting out even faster now but by the 30% mark it has nearly stopped. All Selects are only on the primary key pair..

Comment: I am now disabling the keys before each LOAD INFILE and enabling it after. I would disable it for all tables before I start and enable all after, but as I have been starting and stopping the program I built in something that will check (i.e. read a table) to see if the file was already inserted. That way I am able to start it after each change and see what if any improvement there is with out starting the process again.

Comment: If it is, it is negligible once the 30% of the files are read in. The program gets progressively slower. At 30% it has read in 300k rows to each table. Sure this is a lot of data but I did not think that SQL inserts would slow down at this size.

Answer (score 0):

There's a number of things in your code that could contribute to the speed problems and you are correct in suspecting that the Strings play a role.

Take for example this code:

String rowsString = "";
    // - an extra 1 to not have a comma at the end
    for (int i = 0; i <= numberOfRows - 3; i++) {
        rowsString += "(DATA), \n";
    }
    rowsString += "(DATA)";

Depending on how many rows there are, this is a potential bottle-neck and memory hog. I think it's best if you use a StringBuilder here. I see a lot of String manipulation that are better suited to StringBuilders. Might I suggest you read up on String handling a bit and optimise these, especially where you += Strings?

Then the next question is how is your table designed? There could be things making your inserts slow, like incorrect default lengths for varchars, no indexes or too many indexes etc.

Comment: There are about 7-10k rows in each file. True the program does use up a lot of stack space, but this is not killing the performance. The insert queries are taking up more and more time.

Answer (score 0):

Most databases load data more efficiently if,

- you load in batches of data,
- you load in a relatively small numebr of threads e.g. one or two.

As you add more threads you add more overhead, so you expect it to be slower.

Try using an ExecutorService with a fixed size pool e.g. 2-4 and try loading the data in batches of say 100 at a time in a transaction.

Comment: ok. I limited the threads to two. However again by the 30% mark it is too slow. And when I say too slow I mean it will take upwards of 10 hours to complete. (The ETA estimate I have in the code continually increases. It very well could take more than 10 hours.)

Comment: You are possibly reaching the limit of how much can be uncommited to disk (I could be wrong because I assumed most DB always commit) What I see is in many programs is the amount actually written to disk is much lower than what the application attempts to write.  This runs fine until a limit is reached (about 1/5th of memory on Centos) and the performance drops to the speed written to disk. When the application stops I see there are writes for some time after.

Comment: You should still see an improvement by batching your data, but I suspect you have reached the limit of what your disk can write. Can you check you have a write cache enabled?

Comment: I did batch the data.  The speed did improve at the start but it still drops off. Yes write caching is enabled.

Comment: If you watch the disk activity, e.g. iostat or vmstat, is it fairly constant or does it drop away when your application slows down?

Comment: I am reading from is an SSD and so that activity is minimal. The drive I am writing to is a normal HHD and is yes is variable.

Answer (score 0):

You have several good tried and tested options for speeding up database access.

1. Use an `ExecutorService` for your threads. This may not help speed-wise but it will help you implement the following.
2. Hold a `ThreadLocal` `Connection` instead of making a new connection for every file. Also, obviously, don't close it.
3. Create a single `PreparedStatement` instead of making a new one every time around.
4. Batch up your statement executions.